# De-select kendo treeview node

Tags: kendo-treeview

How to de-select node in kendo treeview ?

I tried with removing class 'k-state-selected' from node.It works fine, but is there any direct method to do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to deselect all nodes in Kendo UI now:

```
var tree = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
treeControl.select($());
```

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/methods/select

Answer (score 0):

First get selected node then find specific span using 'k-state-selected' class then remove it.

```
var treeControl = $("#tree-control ").data("kendoTreeView");
treeControl .select().find("span.k-state-selected")
.removeClass("k-state-selected");
```